# How to configure my own minted environment?

Tags: minted

This code doesn't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\newminted[mycode]{text}{framesep=6pt,framerule=1pt}
\begin{mycode}[highlightlines={1}]
Hello,
world!
\end{mycode}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong with it? I want to have an ability to specific additional configuration for my own minted environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `\newminted` you need to use the `*` form and a mandatory keyval argument, not an optional one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\newminted[mycode]{text}{framesep=6pt,framerule=1pt}
\begin{mycode*}{highlightlines={1}}
Hello,
world!
\end{mycode*}
\end{document}
```